# Include file and line number in python logs so clicking in PyCharm can go to the source line?

Tags: python, logging

I'm new to Python but experienced in Java.   One of the more useful tricks was to have the slf4j backend include file name and line number of the source line for a log statement so IDE's could navigate to that when clicked.

I would like to have the same facility in Python but is inexperienced with the ecosystem.

How do I configure the Python logging library to add this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the [LogRecord attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes) in the formatter of a logger.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format="File: %(filename)s Line: %(lineno)d Message: %(message)s")
logging.warning("this is a log")
```

Output: `File: lineno.py Line: 4 Message: this is a log`

Answer (score 0):

I found by experiment that the following snippet for `File "X", line Y` results in clickable logs in PyCharm.  (The fragment look like a stack trace line).

```
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s    File "%(pathname)s", line %(lineno)s', level=logging.INFO)
```

Sample output:

```
INFO:Found latest date date: None - File "(omitted)\DbConnector.py", line 27
INFO:Did not find latest date date, setting to: 2020-08-11 11:52:43.547400 - File "(omitted)\DbConnector.py", line 31
```

For the record - Stack traces in Python look like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "...\X.py", line 94, in extract_zip_file
    with sftp.open(zip_path, "r") as fi:
TypeError: open() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```